# Cannot Add class in Enum.Extensions namespace, because Enum type (System) is then inavailable

Tags: c#, .net

I have two projects.

1) One (library) that contains Enum extension methods in namespace:

```
namespace Enum.Extensions
{
  public static class EnumerationExtensions
  {

    public static bool Has<T>(this System.Enum type, T value)
    {
      try
      {
        return (((int)(object)type & (int)(object)value) == (int)(object)value);
      }
      catch
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2) Second, Console Applications which has a reference to the library above and tries to use
its new methods:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Enum.Extensions;

namespace XMLExtensionsTest
{
  public enum ProcesInfo
  {
    ifCreate = 1,
    ifRun1 = 2,
    IfRun2 = 4,
    IFRun3 = 8
  }

  class Program
  {   
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      ProcesInfo enumInfo = ProcesInfo.ifCreate;      

      enumInfo = enumInfo.Add(ProcesInfo.IfRun2);
      bool value = enumInfo.Has(ProcesInfo.ifCreate);
      bool value2 = enumInfo.Has(ProcesInfo.ifRun1);
      bool value3 = enumInfo.Has(ProcesInfo.IfRun2);
      bool value4 = enumInfo.Has(ProcesInfo.IFRun3);
    }
  }
}
```

Now, because of that Extensions class all standard Enum types are not accessible.
i cannot write:

```
public void Test(Enum test)
{

}
```

but need:

```
public void Test(System.Enum test)
{
}
```

There are thousands of places where Enum is used without "System".
How to add Extensions class without touching existing Enum class calls?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you rename `Enum.Extensions` to something else... like `Enumeration.Extensions`?

Comment: oh god, I thought that all extensions methods are visible by their namespace, but it turns out that "this" is a key word. Thanks!

Comment: Just add `Enum = System.Enum` at the top, things should work..

Comment: At the top of the library or console project? If I change the namespace: "namespace Enum.Extensions" to "namespace Utils.Enum.Extensions" then is ok. But just for fun, how to keep: "namespace Enum.Extensions" and have all "Enum" calls ok?

Comment: @John to get the second done, do what I said in console project class (or whichever class you have those tons of `System.Enum`. Like this: 

`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Enum.Extensions;
using Enum = System.Enum;

namespace XMLExtensionsTest
{`. You dont have to change anything else.

Comment: @John always address ppl like @ username (without the space, like I did you). Only then they are notified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do any one of the following three options, #3 is your best bet if you do not/cannot change the namespace

1. Rename your `Enum.Extensions` name space
2. Prefix it with something like `MyStuff.Enum.Extensions`
3. [Alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) it like `using MyAlias = Enum.Extensions`

Comment: You probably meant an alias like `Enum = System.Enum`. I don't know if it make sense to have an alias for namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the `namespace` of the `Enum Library`. Which is your first library project having Extensions.

`Enum` is the `Type` name and you are using it as a `namespace` and hence there is ambiguity.